# Допускается ли использование иконок языков программирования и разметки на своих сайтах, визитках и т. д.?

Tags: иконки, юридические-аспекты

Опять же вопрос, объединяющий в себе веб-разработку и юриспруденцию, но поскольку большинство юристов отродясь не слышали про HTML, CSS, PHP и другие веб-технологии, то вероятно, с таким вопросом лучше всё-таки к IT-инженерам.

Могу ли я в свою визитную карточку или на сайт своей фирмы добавлять логотипы HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, C++, Java и т. д., например, чтобы показать область своей специализацией? Красивый список с иконками этих технологий будет смотреться куда лучше, чем убогий маркированный список типа:

> Применяемые технологии:
>
> - HTML5 и CSS3
> - JavaScript
> - PHP
> - Webpack

Comment: Использовать НЕ официальные иконки, а сторонние похожие, которые разрешены к использованию уже их авторами (например, купить их, если продают). В идеале - заказать у того, кто рисует все остальное (ну, или у другого - художники народ узкий, если кто рисует крутейшие реалистичные картины, то иконки в минимализме для него просто унизительны), с обязательной проверкой оригинальности иконок, чтобы не продали чужие. И никакой суеты на пустом месте.

Comment: Кроме прочего, при индивидуальном заказе (да и при покупке) можно подобрать иконки в особом стиле, который подходит к сайту. Скажем, в виде металлической гравировки.

Comment: Боитесь или явно не одобряете пиратство?

Comment: @avp, не одобряю. И если Вы одобряете, то значит Вы ещё не создали хотя бы малый бизнес в области IT.

Comment: Вы что, всерьез думаете, что сможете зарабатывать на своих авторских правах?

Comment: @avp, мы отклонились от темы и перешли в спор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/html/logo/faq.html) идёт под CC-BY-3.0. Его можно использовать достаточно свободно. На сайте можно использовать достаточно свободно, в специально отведённом разделе стоит указать ссылку на автора. В визитке желательно также указать ссылку w3c.org, но думаю не много найдётся людей, которые будут корить за её отсутствие.
- [PHP](http://php.net/download-logos.php) распространяется под CC-BY-SA-4.0 и по идее требует распространять производные работы под той же лицензией. Например будет достаточно выложить макет визитки в открытый доступ. Использование на сайте аналогично предыдущему.
- [Python](https://www.python.org/community/logos/) — по сути является торговой маркой, но позиция распространения довольно либеральна. Возможно разрешат использование в переписке.
- [Java](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/java-licensing-logo-guidelines-1908204.pdf) — Собственность оракла. Скорее всего они не одобрят такое использование. В любом случае это требует предварительного согласования.
- [С++](https://isocpp.org/home/terms-of-use) —  Также торговая марка, использование в не изменённом виде допускается практически в любых целях связанных с C++ без получения предварительного согласия.
- У CSS и JavaScript AFAIK нет официального лого, все сторонние иконки идут под своими лицензиями, скорей всего многие из них достаточно либеральные.

ЗЫ: я не юрист, и не знаю насколько свободные и нет лицензии согласуются с законодательством конкретных стран, а также пользоваться всеми моими советами можно на свой страх и риск.

Comment: Официальное лого C++ - https://isocpp.org/home/terms-of-use

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Наверное, нужно для каждого лого набирать в поисковике **<LanguageName> logo terms of use** =)

Comment: @gbg добавил, спасибо...

Comment: @БоковГлеб, в общем да. =) Ещё можно зайти на вики — там у многих пунктик на лицензионный частоте и на файлы с лого особенно, так что всё довольно точно проставлено со ссылками...